# Mongoose not returning document from mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get Mongoose to query my mongo instance for a specific document (using the _id attribute). I currently have  the following route:

```
router.get('/document/', function (req, res) {
    var getDocuments = function (callback) {
        var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1000 } } };
        var connectionString = 'mongodb://user:password@server:27017/db';
        var pID = req.query.id;
        pID = pID.trim();
        console.log(pID);
        var documentArray = [];

        // Connected handler
        Mongoose.connect(connectionString, function (err) {

            var db = Mongoose.connection.useDb('db');
            var pCollection = db.collection("collection");
            //grab all items from pCollection
            pCollection.find({ '_id': pID }, function (error, pDocument) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                if (pDocument) {
                    // res.send(JSON.stringify(pDocument));       
                    console.log(pDocument);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("nothing");
                }

            });
            db.close();

        });
    };

    getDocuments(function () {

    });
});
```

The result returned is not a json document and does not seem to return a usable value. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT:

I went back and changed the route to the following:

```
 router.get('/document/', function (req, res) {            
        var pID = req.query.id;

        pID = pID.trim();
        console.log(pID);

        Document.findById(pID, function (error, document) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log(document);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

I also created the following model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DocumentSchema = require('../schemas/documents');
var Document = mongoose.model('documents', DocumentSchema, 'Documents');
module.exports = Document;
```

And used the following schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({       
    documenttPK: String,
    locationID: String,
    docName: String,        
    SerialNumber: String,
    documentID: String,
    dateEntered: Date,
    activeFlag: Boolean
});
module.exports = DocumentSchema;
```

My app.js makes a single call to a db file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@server:27017/db');
```

But the result is still null. Is something wrong with the above code?

Comment: For one, you're closing the database connection before the callback passed to `find()` has been called. But besides that, there are other issues: creating a database connection for each request, using Mongoose while not using any Mongoose-specific features, and it's likely that you need to convert `pID` to an `ObjectId` first.

Comment: I changed the code and updated the description, could you take a look at the edit and see if I missed anything?

Comment: That looks much better, although it's unclear to me which collection you want to query (`collection` or `documents`). Plus you shouldn't declare the `_id` field in your schema, it'll be added automatically.

Comment: I just made the change to the schema and fixed the typo. Im currently using Documents as the collection and have called it as the third param in my model; however, I am still receiving a null value.

Comment: So, from the Mongo shell, this returns a result: `db.Documents.find({ _id : THE_ID })` ?

Comment: When I do that in mongo, I am able to get the correct value. I tried this with my program, robomongo and the mongo console